# Lotus notes Database Path

Tags: vba, excel, lotus-domino

I had created a macro which will pull data from from lotus notes and it was working fine. Now what has happened is that the Server name of the lotus note is been changed and my macro is not able to support the new server. not sure y? its giving me an error at searchCount . please have a look? i am giving you the old and new code please suggest if i am missing something.

OLD CODE:

```
Set nSess = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
DSN1 = ("Driver={Lotus NotesSQL Driver (*.nsf)};Server=OLDSERVER Capital Markets;Database=Notes_DBs/GMI_CoreTrack/mlctrack.nsf;Uid=" & myUsername & ";Pwd=" & myPassword & ";")
Call nSess.Initialize(myPassword)
Set db = nSess.GetDatabase("OLDSERVER", "Notes_DBs/GMI_CoreTrack/mlctrack.nsf")
Set iviews = db.GetView("QA\QA Schedule")
strSearchKeyIssue = "FIELD AQAExecDate >= " & StartDate & " AND FIELD AQAExecDate <= " & EndDate
searchCount = iviews.FTSearch(strSearchKeyIssue, 0)
Set viewEntry = iviews.GetFirstDocument
```

NEW CODE:

```
Set nSess = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession") 
DSN1 = ("Driver={Lotus NotesSQL Driver (*.nsf)};Server=NEWSERVER;Database=GMI\mlctrack.nsf;Uid=" & myUsername & ";Pwd=" & myPassword & ";")
Call nSess.Initialize(myPassword)
Set db = nSess.GetDatabase("NEWSERVER", "GMI\mlctrack.nsf")
Set iviews = db.GetView("QA\QA Schedule")
strSearchKeyIssue = "FIELD AQAExecDate >= " & StartDate & " AND FIELD AQAExecDate <= " & EndDate
searchCount = iviews.FTSearch(strSearchKeyIssue, 0)
```

Getting error message at the above line : Runtime Error 80040fa0

```
Set viewEntry = iviews.GetFirstDocument
```

Comment: Please check that the DB is full text indexed in the new server?

Comment: How to check that as this is my company's lotus notes i may not have access to check that.

Comment: I check with my IT Team the DB is full text indexed

Comment: Check it yourself.  Open it and try to do a full text search.

Comment: You all me to say to check if the below search query is working in lotus notes search field?

FIELD AQAExecDate >= 7/1/2014 AND FIELD AQAExecDate <= 7/31/2014

I check the above query and its not working and its giving error Relational operator are not supported in text field.

Comment: Previously in my macro I use to search in the QA\QA Schedule tab with the below query and it use to work. But now we giving me an error message in lotus notes itself that “Relational operators are not supported in the text field.” 

FIELD AQAExecDate >= 7/1/2014 AND FIELD AQAExecDate <= 7/31/2014

Can you please have a look? 

As of now i can see for the AQAExecDate we have only 2 fields contain and does not contain. in Search field section of lotus notes

Comment: what the error tells that the AQAExecDate is TEXT and not DATE thus you can't search AQAExecDate >= 7/1/2014.  I'm not sure I understand you: Previous to DB move on a new serer THIS query was working ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an UNK table problem.

When the field first created on that specific replica, if it has been marked as a text field in the UNK table, even you have date values, you may not search the view for date values.

UNK Table is specific for each replica. So that might be why you are having the issue on the new server.

Here are the details: http://www.intec.co.uk/full-text-search-musings/

Solution is explained here: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21261002

> To find where this may be occurring, you can use Notespeek to do a
>   search for the field and look for the reference which is incorrect and
>   change it. Once you have fixed the field the UNK table will still need
>   to be rebuilt as well as the full text index. To do this you would.
>
> 1. Delete the full text index.
> 2. Compact the database. This rebuilds the UNK table.
> 3. Reindex the database.